# Error: Argument lists differ in length

Tags: java, arrays

```
private class ButtonSelect implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object Ps = e.getSource();
        String selectedLanguage = (String) languageList.getSelectedItem();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(StudentRecordsGUI.this,
                "You selected the language: " + selectedLanguage);
        if (selectedLanguage != "English") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(StudentRecordsGUI.this,
            "I'm sorry. The language you have selected is currently not available. Please try again.");
        }
        else
            setVisible(false);
            new Record (student, this, "Student Records");
    }
} //end class ButtonSelect
```

Error:

```
java:52: error: constructor Record in class StudentRecordsGUI.Record cannot be applied to given types;
                new Record (student, this, "Student Records");
                ^
  required: Student
  found: ArrayList<Student>,StudentRecordsGUI.ButtonSelect,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I need to use:

```
ArrayList<Student> student = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

to get information from `Student` class, but it won't take it. How can I edit this line so it will?

Comment: post your `Record` class?

Comment: The error message is extremely clear. Have at least tried reading and understanding it?

Comment: There is also another problem you might not be aware of. Since you are not using curly braces in the 'else' clause, it only contains the `setVisible` line. The indented `new Record(...)` is not running in the `else` clause.

Comment: This won't solve your improper calling of the constructor there, but please compare strings with the `equals()` method and NOT with `==`. Otherwise your if will never evaluate to `true`.

Comment: helderdarocha - Nope, doesn't make a difference.
Martin Dinov - That part does not have any errors, so it doesn't matter.
JB Nizet - It is clear. So what code do I have to use to fix it?

Comment: So, after slapping all those who gave comments in the attempt to help you, you might continue with that what lakshman said: Post your `Record` class. But regardless of that: The `Record` constructor expects *one* `Student` as its argument. Give it that `Student`, and it will work.